# SimpleCursorAdapter in ICS

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, simplecursoradapter, android-loadermanager

I need a  SimpleCursorAdapter in my project. I've written code for this in 2.3 version. But i could not add this in ICS. It shows `SimpleCursorAdapter(context, layout, c, from, to)` is deprecated and the new one is `SimpleCursorAdapter(context, layout, c, from, to, flags)`.

A new parameter "flags" is included in this.
What should I add in the place of flags? What does this indicate?

Comment: Are you using CursorLoader as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quote the Android reference, the flag parameter is of the following:

```
public static final int **FLAG_AUTO_REQUERY**
```

Since: API Level 11

This constant is deprecated. This option is discouraged, as it results in Cursor queries being performed on the application's UI thread and thus can cause poor responsiveness or even Application Not Responding
 errors. As an alternative, use LoaderManager with a CursorLoader.

If set the adapter will call requery() on the cursor whenever a
 content change notification is delivered. Implies

```
 FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER. Constant Value: 1 (0x00000001)
```

.

```
public static final int **FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER**
```

Since: API
 Level 11

If set the adapter will register a content observer on the cursor and
 will call onContentChanged() when a notification comes in. Be careful
 when using this flag: you will need to unset the current Cursor from
 the adapter to avoid leaks due to its registered observers. This flag
 is not needed when using a CursorAdapter with a CursorLoader. Constant
 Value: 2 (0x00000002)

However, the new pattern for Honeycomb+ is to use a cursorLoader to manage the cursor for you. In this case, you pass 0 as the flags parameter.

[**Read more (with tutorials) on CursorLoader + CursorAdapter**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/loaders.html)

Comment: The error has gone.. but it still doesn't work :( all the data from database are selected at once..